# how to yammer feed filtering

Tags: feed, yammer

We are integrating Yammer with our web application. One of our requirement it to display the my yammer feeds and the feeds of topics which I am following. We are using yammer widget in yam.connect.embedFeed() our pages. Is there any way to do the filtering?

Is there any modification possible in the below code to achieve this?

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  "feedType": "user",
  "feedId": 1530760345,
  "config": {
  "use_sso": false,
  "header": true,
  "footer": true,
  "showOpenGraphPreview": false,
  "defaultToCanonical": false,
  "hideNetworkName": false
},
"container": "#embedded-feed"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change feedType to topic, and set the feedID to the topic ID. This will show all messages with a particular topic ID. More user-specific filtering is not supported.